# How to reduce code redundancy in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got these two calculated fields in my query:

```
CASE
    WHEN TRN.TOTAL_VALUE_T = 0 THEN '00000000000'
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN CC.PORT_CURRENCY1 = 'CAD' THEN RIGHT('00000000000' + REPLACE(LTRIM(STR(TRN.TOTAL_VALUE_T + TRN.TAXES, 11, 2)), '.', ''), 11) 
            WHEN CC.PORT_CURRENCY1 = 'USD' THEN RIGHT('00000000000' + REPLACE(LTRIM(STR((TRN.TOTAL_VALUE_T + TRN.TAXES) * DBO.fnGetExchangeRate(TRN.TRADE_DATE, 'USD', 'CAD'), 11, 2)), '.', ''), 11)
    END
END AS TX_PRIX_CAD,

CASE 
    WHEN T.TRANS_TYPE in ('ADD','DELIV') THEN
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT currencyTitle FROM DBO.GetPrice(TRN.SEC_NO, TRN.TRADE_DATE)) = '' THEN TX_PRIX_CAD 
        END
END AS TX_MNT_BRUT
```

You see, the second field (TX_MNT_BRUT) must equal the first one (TX_PRIX_CAD) under certain conditions.

Problem when doing this is SQL is telling me that TX_PRIX_CAD is not a valid column name, I guess because the column name does not exist physically in the table.

How could I achieve this without repeating the code in TX_PRIX_CAD in TX_MNT_BRUT ?

Thanks.

Comment: The derived table allude to by @TabAlleman, is simply a subquery with an alias.

Comment: You might find this post helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177740/calculated-fields-within-sql-query/30178059#30178059

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks. I've upvoted that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to nest the select statement e.g.

```
SELECT <other_columns>, TX_PRIX_CAD, 
CASE 
WHEN T.TRANS_TYPE in ('ADD','DELIV') THEN
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT currencyTitle FROM DBO.GetPrice(TRN.SEC_NO, TRN.TRADE_DATE)) = '' THEN TX_PRIX_CAD 
    END
END AS TX_MNT_BRUT
FROM (

    SELECT 
    <other columns>,
    CASE
        WHEN TRN.TOTAL_VALUE_T = 0 THEN '00000000000'
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN CC.PORT_CURRENCY1 = 'CAD' THEN RIGHT('00000000000' + REPLACE(LTRIM(STR(TRN.TOTAL_VALUE_T + TRN.TAXES, 11, 2)), '.', ''), 11) 
            WHEN CC.PORT_CURRENCY1 = 'USD' THEN RIGHT('00000000000' + REPLACE(LTRIM(STR((TRN.TOTAL_VALUE_T + TRN.TAXES) * DBO.fnGetExchangeRate(TRN.TRADE_DATE, 'USD', 'CAD'), 11, 2)), '.', ''), 11)
        END 
    END
    END AS TX_PRIX_CAD,
    T.TRANS_TYPE
    FROM <table_name>
)
```